# aggregate on amount column by month - sql

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql, aggregate-functions, aggregate

I can't seem to figure out how to aggregate this table. I need to figure out from this table what is the amount aggregated by a month. So I have some projects and a duration per project, average income per month (for each project). For example, I would like to see what is the total amount for all project May 2011. Here is the original table:

```
Year    Month   Amount  Duration (month)    average per month
2012    1       7       4                   1.75
2012    2       6       5                   1.2
2012    3       5       6                   0.833333333
2012    4       4       6                   0.666666667
2012    5       9       5                   1.8
2012    6       10      4                   2.5
2012    7       20      3                   6.666666667
2011    4       13      2                   6.5
2011    3       3       10                  0.3
2011    12      4       11                  0.363636364
2011    2       5       12                  0.416666667
2011    3       7       3                   2.333333333
2010    5       8       4                   2
2010    7       3       6                   0.5
2010    9       4       7                   0.571428571
2010    11      5       8                   0.625
2010    1       6       8                   0.75
2010    2       7       8                   0.875
2010    3       8       9                   0.888888889
2010    4       9       1                   9
```

I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Could you include expected results? I don't quite get what you need. For example, is (year=2011, month=3) part of May 2011 because its duration of 3 months means it's active in May 2011?

Comment: @EdGibbs you are correct in your assumption. I will try to add expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming year is varchar  and month/duration int (if not, you may need to convert them as applicable) you can do something like this:

```
select sum(amount) from yourtable
where YearMonth between
period_add(year&'01',month-1) and period_add(year&'01',month+duration-2)
```

being YearMonth a string with the year/month to be queried, in your example would be '201105'

for a number of year/months you can create a one-column table:

```
create table yearmonths(yearmonth varchar(6));
insert into yearmonths values
('201101'),('201102'),(201103),
('201104'),('201105'),(201106)
```

and join it to your table:

```
    Select yearmonth,sum(amount)
    from yearmonths y
    left join yourtable t
    on(y.yearmonth between period_add(year&'01',month-1)and period_add(year&'01',month+duration-2)
    group by yearmonth
```

Comment: @Paul Kar. this is mysql; for tsql you can use dateadd and cast (or datefromparts if SQL2012) to set the periods.

Comment: Thank you for this solution, but I was hoping to get that for all the data in the table. Not just for 1 month. Maybe some type of a while loop would be useful here.

Comment: you can also create a year/month table and join it to yourtable on yearmonth between periodstart and perioend.

Comment: that's exactly what I am struggling with. How would I create that year/month table? I am assuming you meant also to insert the amounts to the relevant months?

Comment: I think you can create a one-column temp table with all the year/month you are interested in and then join it to yourtable and follow the same logic. is it mysql or tsql?

Comment: @Paul Kar. I added a mysql example that will work for n numbers of months.